# How to remove "[" and "]" signs from array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, list

I'm using `react.js` for building my dashboard

I want to convert an array like this (old version) `[ {...}, {...}, {...} ]` into this (new version) `{...}, {...}, {...}` in `javascript`

So I can put the new version of the array inside a JSON array like this `[ {...}, newArray ]`

I know a `map` function returns an array and I know it's a silly question but I wonder how

here is my code:

```js
const siteProfilesList = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI']
const pagesList = ['Dashboard', 'Routes', 'Payload']

const siteProfileNavigationsList = siteProfilesList.map((item, index) => {
    let menu = {}
    menu['_tag'] = 'CSidebarNavDropdown'
    menu['name'] = item
    menu['_children'] = pagesList.map((pageItem, pageIndex) => {
        let pageMenu = {}
        pageMenu['_tag'] = 'CSidebarNavItem'
        pageMenu['name'] = pageItem
        pageMenu['to'] = `/${pageItem.toLowerCase()}/location=${item.toLowerCase()}`
        return pageMenu
    })
    return menu
})

const navigations = [
    {
        _tag: 'CSidebarNavTitle',
        _children: ['Site Profile']
    },
    siteProfileNavigationsList
]

export default navigations
```

I know it's a silly question but I just wonder about the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that what you want? I use `flat()`.

```js
const siteProfilesList = ["ABC", "DEF", "GHI"];
const pagesList = ["Dashboard", "Routes", "Payload"];

const siteProfileNavigationsList = siteProfilesList.map((item, index) => {
  let menu = {};
  menu["_tag"] = "CSidebarNavDropdown";
  menu["name"] = item;
  menu["_children"] = pagesList.map((pageItem, pageIndex) => {
    let pageMenu = {};
    pageMenu["_tag"] = "CSidebarNavItem";
    pageMenu["name"] = pageItem;
    pageMenu[
      "to"
    ] = `/${pageItem.toLowerCase()}/location=${item.toLowerCase()}`;
    return pageMenu;
  });
  return menu;
});

const navigations = [
  {
    _tag: "CSidebarNavTitle",
    _children: ["Site Profile"],
  },
  siteProfileNavigationsList,
];

console.log(navigations.flat());
```

Comment: wow I just realize that there is ```flat``` function, thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is the [<strike>destructuring</strike> spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```
const arr = [x, y, z]
const anotherArr = [a, b]
const combined = [...anotherArr, ...arr] // [a, b, x, y, z]
```

The `...` "removes" the brackets arround the array.

Comment: This is not destructuring, this is [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: @VLAZ oh yeah whoops

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to remove the brackets, you just need to concatenate your two arrays https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp