# javacsript array map with double [[ ]] data

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have this array:

`[ [ { "data1": 1, "data2": 2, }, { "data1": 1, "data2": 2, } ] ]`

how can i remove the first parenthesis? i tried with reduce or map but return an error:

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reduce') or Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map').

I have to retrieve some data inside it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: use `flat()`, duplicated here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68033265/how-to-remove-and-signs-from-array-in-javascript/68033342#68033342

Comment: Using `.reduce()` on that array will not throw that error. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: What do you mean? There are no parenthesis ( ) in your code, only square brackets and curly brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use array.flat() here

```
let x =[ [ { "data1": 1, "data2": 2, }, { "data1": 1, "data2": 2, } ] ]

let y = x.flat()

console.log(y) // [ { data1: 1, data2: 2 }, { data1: 1, data2: 2 } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in an array `arr`, there are a couple of ways:

1. Just do `arr[0].map(...)` (if your data looks like in your example)
2. Use [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap). If there is nesting like `[ [ obj1, obj2 ], [ obj3, obj4 ] ]` flatMap turns it to `[obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4]`

Example:

```
arr.flatMap(_ => _)
```

Edit: As others have mentioned, [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) works just as well. It depends whether you want to perform some operations within the `flatMap` also, or to get an array of only the `data1` properties of the objects in your example:

```
arr.flatMap(el => el["data1"])
```